# How to select this id in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html code like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="supportButton" id="whitelist.onCancelUploadButton" >
```

whose `id` is `whitelist.onCancelUploadButton`, but when I try in jquery like this:

```
$('#whitelist.onCancelUploadButton')
```

Its always returning `[]` (nothing).

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: I'm user2727841 check my code its working I've tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape it using `\`, since it is a string the `\` need to be again escaped using `\\`

```
$('#whitelist\\.onCancelUploadButton')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('[id="whitelist.onCancelUploadButton"]')
```

The problem is that according to CSS selector rules, you're actually asking for an element whose `id` is 'whitelist' and is having the `class` 'onCancelUploadButton'.

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

use space between

```
$('#whitelist .onCancelUploadButton')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its working I've tested this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("input[value='Cancel']").attr("id"));
});
```

HTML code

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" class="supportButton" id="whitelist.onCancelUploadButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use:

```
$('[id=whitelist.onCancelUploadButton]')
```

or

```
ID="whitelist.onCancelUploadButton";
$('[id='+ID+']')
```